What are the sufficient conditions for the identity of consciousness at different locations in space and time?
Notation
To make the discussion clearer, I will use the following notation:

P: A person or individual under consideration.
C(P@{t,x}): The consciousness of person P at time t and spatial location x in spacetime.
C(P@{t₁,x₁}) = C(P@{t₂,x₂}): The claim that the consciousness of P at time t₁ and location x₁ is identical to the consciousness of P at time t₂ and location x₂.


Introduction
The question in the title subsumes many other related identity questions about consciousness. It asks whether the consciousness of a person at one point in spacetime is the same as their consciousness at another point. Addressing this requires examining different scenarios and thought experiments that challenge our understanding of the conditions under which consciousness retains its identity.

Examples of Identity Questions

Teleportation
If person P at time t₁ and position x₁ is teleported via a machine to a faraway location at time t₂ and position x₂ (t₂ > t₁), is C(P@{t₂,x₂}) = C(P@{t₁,x₁})?
In other words, is the consciousness of P after teleportation identical to the consciousness of P before teleportation?

Transportation at the Speed of Light
Now replace teleportation with transportation. In particular, imagine person P is moving at the speed of light inside a spaceship. Is C(P@{t₂,x₂}) = C(P@{t₁,x₁})?

Waking Up After Sleep
If P goes to sleep at time t₁ and wakes up the next day at time t₂, is C(P@{t₂}) = C(P@{t₁})?

Waking Up After a Long Coma
Suppose person P enters a coma at time t₁ and wakes up six months later at time t₂, regaining consciousness. Is C(P@{t₂}) = C(P@{t₁})?

Cloning
If a perfect clone P' is produced from P, is C(P') = C(P)?

Aging
Suppose P is 10 years old at time t₁ and 90 years old at time t₂. Is C(P@{t₂}) = C(P@{t₁})?

Replacing Atoms One at a Time
If all the atoms of P at time t₁ are fully replaced, one at a time, by time t₂, is C(P@{t₂}) = C(P@{t₁})?



Main Question
NOTE: this is the only question I'm asking, the others were just examples that are subsumed under this one.
All these examples can be subsumed under the general question of defining consciousness in a more fundamental sense and tracking its identity in space and time. Concretely:
Given a person P at time t₁ and location x₁ in spacetime, what are the sufficient conditions for asserting that C(P@{t₂,x₂}) = C(P@{t₁,x₁})?
In other words, what are the sufficient conditions for the identity of consciousness at different locations in space and time?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Under reductive physicalism...
Under reductive physicalism, where your consciousness reduces to brain activity, every changing atom would technically result in a "different" person, even if they are 99.999999999% the same. So they may only be different in a technical sense, not in a "meaningful" sense (when a change is "meaningful" is more a question of semantics).
If we're talking about consciousness, we may say each of the smallest instances of time that "you" experience, results in a new consciousness, as those sensory perceptions (or thoughts) causes electrical signal to be fired across your brain, and as it affects neurons and brain chemicals. This may result in new thoughts (which are themselves brain activity), which may in turn affect your brain, and so on. Your consciousness is also affected by subconscious brain activity.
Periods of unconsciousness are periods where there is a lack of consciousness (dreaming aside). So there'd be a consciousness before you lose consciousness, and a consciousness afterwards, and those would be different by the amount your brain changed across that period. If you had brain surgery, it's probably a lot. If you nodded off for 5 minutes, it's probably not that much.
The same consciousness between 2 people?
Consciousness between two people can theoretically be equal if one has the exact same memories, emotions, thoughts, biases, etc. Although, for any two actual people living in the actual world (beyond some time after birth, perhaps), it's a statistical impossibility for them to have identical memories, no matter how similar their past may be (never mind their biology being and remaining the same throughout their entire lives). Keep in mind that they would need to remember growing up in the same town in the same country, with the same friends and family, with the same memories of what news happened and what shows they watched, and they'd need to have been in the exact same situations in the exact same sequence, for every situation, no matter how mundane, across their entire lives.
One might loosen the definition of "the same" a bit and similar memories could result in "the same" person if those result in the same ways of thinking. Also, some memories of experiences may be inaccessible to your consciousness (temporarily or permanently), so it could be said to be negligible aside from any additional effects such experiences or memories had on your brain. But in a strict sense, we can disregard such speculation.
One could consider the above in the form of the brain being identical. Although it's also conceivable that different brains could produce the same consciousness. It's been demonstrated that some parts of the brain could adopt different functions under some circumstances (even if this is an exception, commonly to adopt for a function lacking previously, rather than being the norm).
Yes, I am saying that conscious experiences have multiple realizability, and could, in theory, also be replicable in machines or other things. That is, if we manage to appropriately replicate all the corresponding parts, and put together appropriately. It's possible that we eventually run into an emulation problem of being unable to tell whether emulated consciousness is itself conscious, because we judge consciousness through behaviour... although I don't think modern AI is anywhere close to that. And no, I don't consider this to be an argument against reductive physicalism. At most, it may be an uncomfortable reality for some people (or it's an argument against some weaker form of reductive physicalism). Much like you can have different computers with different hardware, which follow the same processing process and generate the same things on the screen, so to it might be possible to produce the same consciousness with different "hardware" (brains and brain-like things).
So you're a different person every moment?
Well, yes and no.
The "you" preserves and connects across time exactly as much as your biology does - no more, no less.
Every moment, you transform into the "you" that follows via corresponding physical changes. One might also say that bodily death is only really ceasing of consciousness, while after that, your brain and body decompose and transform into other physical forms and persist as part of other objects (which is just about the most "spiritual" sentence you'd get out of me).
There isn't really a strict categorical distinction between any of those things. The issue is more that humans want to fit everything neatly into all these little boxes we make up, but often reality stubbornly refuses to conform, like how a mountain may stubbornly refuse to get out of the way if you're trying to get to the other side.
If we're being pedantic, we might say there exists a collection of consciousnesses across time within some linked dynamic collection of atoms. It's useful, at the very least, to refer to that as "a person", as "you", as "me", to consider that as a unit when talking about rights, to think of "my future self" and "my past self", etc.

How would you answer this?

@user80226 I'd probably just reiterate much of what I said in this answer: our idea of identity doesn't exist in reality in quite as discrete, static and irreducible fashion as we might imagine it. The past "you" has stopped existing, at least in that it's transformed via brain changes into the present "you", who has the memories of past "you"s, and that creates the perception of continuity. And I guess also something like what Philomath said, and you're only aware of the moments you're aware - you can't experience the non-experience that may or may not exist between each experienced moment.

Would you agree then that there is no self that persists over time?

@user80226 Any "self" (to the extent that it isn't an illusion) persists via one's biology. The illusion is that it's a discrete or static self - the same one for one's whole life. But most people already accept that there are changes, and that illusion barely, if at all, exists for me. I don't feel all that similar to my past selves.

I highly recommend Reasons and Persons by the late Derek Parifit. He spends a lot of time on exactly this issue. The issue of personal identity revolves around when something is a copy vs a continuation of an earlier process.
Essentially, it is not enough that two experiences seem identical -- they must share psychological continutiy to be considered part of the same experience as opposed to two separate experiences.
Given this, if your brain underwent fission (e.g., split brain) there would be two of you with equal claim to be the “true” you.
Epistemically, we can make sense of this by thinking of it as a probabilistic assignment from the single you now to one of the “future yous”;however, this is only an epistemic probability not an ontological probability.

It is always a pleasure to read Derek Parfit. His writing style is so clear and concise. No need for t1 or t2...

@Annika Is Derek Parifit's view compatible with the self persisting over time being an illusion? In other words, how would he answer that question?

@user80226 yes — in the sense of self as an unchanging, indivisible entity. His split brain thought experiments show us that at any moment we are a self, as a psychological construct developed by our brain.

I think I still don't understand. Let me quickly test my poor understanding by guessing what he would answer to the 7 example identity questions in the OP. Would Parfit answer: 1) Yes; 2) Yes; 3) Yes; 4) Yes; 5) No; 6) Yes; 7) Yes, and if so, why? In other words, I think there is significant room for making the answer more detailed and precise and less vague.

For example: What is a process? What is the continuation of a process? Does sleep interrupt the process? Does coma interrupt the process? Does teleportation interrupt the process? Does transportation interrupt the process? Does cloning multiply the process? Does changing atoms interrupt the process?

@user80226 - it’s a bit overwhelming to have to answer multiple questions in a single post. I don’t have space to rehash all of Parfit’s ideas here but please take a look at the links and maybe revisit your questions after that. Approximately, if you can trace a path from one brain to another you have psychological continuity

OP: "What are the sufficient conditions for the ontological identity of consciousness at different locations in space and time?"
You yourself know that you are the same person yesterday and today. Even if many of your cells have aged and regenerated, psychically you know who you are as your most basic (human) existence, known first-hand, experientially.  However, psychical experience is not locatable in coordinate space.  Inner experience is to the physicality of limbs, organs and furniture as energy is to atoms and molecules. Not that experience is energy, it's just completely different from physicality in a way that the energy analogy might convey. And it is in this non-physical, experiential existence that identity is established as one says "I am myself."  (X is X)

I think you're forgetting that there is physical pain.

Casting sensation in general as a form of pressure or resistance (of sound or touch etc.) then we can consider that "if "Reality" gets defined as "the character of resisting" … Resistance characterizes the 'external world' in the sense of entities within-the-world, … 'Consciousness of Reality' is itself a way of Being-in-the-world. Every 'problematic of the external world' comes back necessarily to this basic existential phenomenon." SZ 211. So the cognitive subject can be conscious of sensible reality.

This is a brilliant question and it really strikes at the core feature of consciousness.
We often notice that philosophers of mind start their discussion of consciousness with how "mysterious" a phenomenon it is. It's not a long time since modern philosophers started grappling with the peculiar nature of consciousness and wondering about it. Since I have already proposed a Phd thesis on this very topic, I may share some thoughts here.
When one contemplates the nature of consciousness with respect to all other phenomena, one is struck by some curious unique features. First is how its reality is in some fundamental and integral sense associated with properties that we so commonly but loosely use in our daily language in reference to all sorts of other phenomena. These are unity, identity, combination, multiplicity, synthesis, dissolution, stability, volatility, etc.
If one sufficiently contemplates the nature of consciousness, which is primarily done through the consciousness's own power to self-reflect (another intriguing feature), one realizes how all those properties named are encountered in internal subjective operations of consciousness as if consciousness unites all those diverse and opposite qualities.
First of all consciousness seems to be fundamentally stable in time despite going through all sorts of changes involving various perceptions, thoughts, states, etc. Yet in some fundamental sense it remains stable in that it can recognize itself throughout all these changes. From this derives other properties of consciousness such as identity and its preservation property known as memory.
This has been the most robust argument by dualists who argue for immateriality of human consciousness.
When Kant struggled to negate the stability feature with his thought experiment involving a hypothetical transference of all mental states and memories of a human subject to another in order to postulate a scenario in which the stability and identity of consciousness is undermined, the great philosopher rather amateurishly failed to appreciate that in his example, subject's consciousness would actually take note of its mental states leaving its domain, thus ironically nothing actually leaving its domain and therefore forgetting nothing in actual reality, hence the identity remaining intact! In case the subject is postulated to be unconscious during the transference period, one then wonders how those mental states can be accessed in the first place before transference!
Nevertheless circumstances in which we forget certain things or go through periods of unconsciousness may suggest that consciousness is not always stable or continuous, but we know that despite these temporary lapses, consciousness almost always restores itself and its memories. So it may be that consciousness has deeper layers than the one operating normally in us, which never loses or forgets anything. Subliminal consciousness has been already postulated since well over a century by some psychologist and parapsychologists. This theory allows for preservation of memory on a deeper layer even in people suffering from extreme Alzheimer. Under a dualist survivalist theory, physiological disorders in the brain may be interpreted as only an obstacle for consciousness to fully permeate the physical body in worldly life, but having no problem to operate fully on a higher plane.
Some practitioners of lucid dreaming and out-of-body projection report experiences in which memories of their encounters in these alter states of consciousness often lapse when returning to normal consciousness. Keeping those memories require dramatic consciousness effort to affect a sort of "memory download" from those higher states to the lower states when going through the transition ("waking up"). Interestingly they speak of experiences in which they could recollect those normally inaccessible memories only after re-entering those altered sates. So this is an additional evidence showing that consciousness never actually forgets and oblivion is a only a feature of lower layers of consciousness imposed by physical/worldly/physiological limitations.
Now in the light of the above, you can see that the identity of consciousness can only be determined by itself which takes place by its own intuition. No external conditions or criteria will be adequate. Signs of continuous memories observed externally in a subject are convenient measure for an outside observer, but not a definite criterion. Indeed, in cases of multiple personality or dissociative disorder, multiple centers of consciousness are suspected in a single body sometimes with one personality aware of the memories of the other personality but not the other way around. In these cases, apparent signs of continuous memory doesn't necessarily point to one subject/identity.
