Many Worlds Interpretation and the Self
If the Many Worlds Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics is correct and the universe splits with every quantum event, then is there an actual self that exists over time? One way of looking at it is that right now there is a complete self which disappears and many different selves appear in the next moment. Another way is that each moment in time there is a self (or selves) but it and its consciousness only lasts a brief moment and it has an illusion of continuity based on memories and thoughts of the future, and there is no continuous self either in the past or in the future. So the self that exists five minutes from now is no more me than the self of the person standing next to me. I will never become the self of five minutes from now or experience its experiences. If the universe is constantly splitting I don’t see how a person over time exists.

Hi! Welcome to Philosophy Stack Exchange :) You may be interested in this question and the answers: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/120829/what-are-the-sufficient-conditions-for-the-identity-of-consciousness-at-differen/120984#120984

Don't think of it as the universe splitting with every event. That's the pop-science version. The real MWI says that the wave function evolves according to certain rules and that it never collapses, so the superposition effects remain "real". (disclaimer: I am not a physicist).

The quick way to solve this is to recognize that you've discovered a new skin for Zeno's Paradox, and the same solutions apply.

So the self that exists five minutes from now is no more me than the self of the person standing next to me.

That's the case with or without MWI quantum buzzwords though. We all have instants in time which changed us; but even without anything important happening, we're still 5 minutes older. You can divide this up however finely you want, and it remains as true as you want it to be for the quantum of time you choose.
For MWI, the key difference to remember is that the self doing the observing is the self on your specific branch, for all branches over all time. From your POV, nothing unexpected happens because it's continuous, just like Zeno's arrow moving a tiny distance.

I won't rehash the commentary in my linked question, but first you need to decide on how you want to define continuity of identity, then you can see how it plays out in the many worlds interpretation.
We also need to think about time - it may not be that reality is actively splitting every moment but that you are traversing a block, 4D  universe, with uncountably many actual worlds. In such a case, all probability reduces to epistemic uncertainty as to which "thread" your particular consciousness is attached to. We instead talk of densities of "world lines" through the multiverse, which we apply conditional epistemic probability to so we can get some statistical conclusions.
So one way to make this make more sense is that indeed you are splitting constantly but at each moment, there is a distribution over some possible worlds and you can think of your experience at the next time moment to be "random" over these possibilities (since each instance of you in a split will feel like they  are the "true" you) - however, all possibilities obtain..
What dies in this interpretation is the idea of a permanent, abiding soul that is "conserved" over time for purposes of moral/spiritual development.

It's the ship of Theseus problem. What we call the "self" is like what we call "Theseus' ship"; it's simply a convenient abstraction for social and legal purposes, not something inherent to reality. When you consider teleporters or many-worlds branching, it's clear that what you call the "self" is merely an arbitrary label.
But there is a related question that isn't arbitrary and could have concrete consequences. If you have $5 and the ability to decide how to distribute the $5 among multiple future instances of yourself, what decision should you make?
In situations where the "self" label is less ambiguous - without multiple future copies - we would usually say that you just keep the $5 for "yourself." But with the copies it becomes a question of altruism. Which copies deserve it most?
This question is at least self-adjacent. We can define the "U-self" (utility-self) to be the self for the purposes of utility maximization; the weighted set of future people whose utility you are trying to maximize. In this case, it would be the people that you wish to give the $5 to. In most cases, for most people in the absence of MWI, their U-self is localized mostly to a single future person. But with MWI or teleporters, the U-self would be distributed, perhaps evenly, across many future people.
There may be reasons not to distribute your U-self evenly. Perhaps some of the future versions of you are very different from you, mentally. Perhaps they have committed serious and malicious crimes without a good enough justification in the judgment of current-you. Then you would assign them lower weights in the U-self; you would wish to give them less of the $5, if any.
If we extrapolate, what seems to matter most for the U-self is how much a future person shares your ideals and goals, or departs from them only in ways you would see as reasonable if you had enough information.
